# Video file does not appear under Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, video, iphone

I have a Windows 10 pc and attached an iPhone 6S to it. All files appear in Windows Explorer except one. It is a 4K Video going over 13 minutes. Is it too big? Is the file system the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install iTunes to get a better driver. With this the 4 GB file is recognized. The default Win 10 driver can't do this ...